# Find substrings in A found in B

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have the string `A`: `'fytzgearld'` and the string B: `'gearyd'`. I wish to find the main substrings from `B` that are in `A`. These substrings are: `('gear', 'd')`. So to clarify, even though `'gea'` is also present in A, it is not of interest to me since it is itself a subset of `'gear'`. `'y'` is also in both but comes in the wrong order since it comes before 'gear' in `A` and after it in `B`.

I've been trying to write a function to establish these substrings but have really struggled. Here is my attempt so far:

```
def subs(s,m,branch=0):

    if s in m: 
        yield s
        return     

    if len(s) == 1: return

    if branch == 1: yield from subs(s[:-1],m,0) 
    yield from subs(s[1:],m,1)
```

Which gives the following:

```
['gea', 'gear', 'gear', 'gear', 'ear', 'ar', 'r', 'gear', 'gear', 'ear', 'ar', 'r', 'gear', 'ear', 'ar', 'r', 'ear', 'ar', 'r', 'ar', 'r', 'r', 'd']
```

So I am getting lots of subset strings within 'gear' as well which I don't need. How might I improve my function?

**UPDATE**

So just to clarify. I wish to compare surnames with each other and this is why I am trying to find the common substrings. For this reason, the order of the substrings is significant. The 'y' common to `'fytzgearld'` and `'gearyd'` is not representative of a relationship between the two names, however the 'd' at the end is.

Comment: Looks like you need a modification of an algorithm that finds longest subsequence.

Comment: what are the expected substrings in case if `B` would be `dygearyd` ? Can you consider that case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ('y', 'gear', 'd')

Comment: Find a longest substring, remove it from both and repeat?

Comment: @splash58 This will result in the y's matching which is not what I want as explained above.

Comment: seems you need split by the longest substring and work with each part

Comment: What about the case `A = 'hellahellish'`, `B = 'llamacalls`? `lla` is in both; `ll` is in both _twice_. Should `lla` mean that `ll` is excluded, even though `ll` is present in other places as well?

Comment: @Snild Dolkow I've update my question now to clarify that I am working with surnames. I think that the two words you give should match as follows: ('lla', 'll', 's')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer but it may not be the one you want.

The algorithm you are trying to implement is known as [“longest common substring.”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Python includes an implementation of it which works for any sequence type.

```
import difflib


def matching_blocks(a, b):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    # last block is a dummy block
    mb = sm.get_matching_blocks()[:-1]
    return [a[m.a:m.a + m.size] for m in mb]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(matching_blocks(
        'fytzgearld', 'gearyd'
        )))
```

Comment: Note you might want to turn off the junk filter in your own application. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my very quick and dirty solution

```
def subs(s,m,branch=0):

if s in m:
    yield s
    return

if len(s) == 1: return


common = []
commons = []
lengths = []
for l in s:
    if l in m:
        common.append(l)
    else:
        if len(common) > 0:
            commons.append(common)
            lengths.append(len(common))
            common = []
if len(common) > 0:
    commons.append(common)
    lengths.append(len(common))
for idx, common in enumerate(commons):
    if len(common) >= max(lengths[idx:]):
        yield ''.join(common)

for s in subs('fytzgearld', 'gearyd'):
    print(s)
```

EDIT to not return 'y'

Comment: This outputs ('y', 'gear','d') however the 'y''s should not match as explained in my question.